# Need help in understanding the logic for the algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm

There was an online coding event yesterday on Codechef, and I can't figure out how to solve [one of the questions from it](http://www.codechef.com/ALKH2013/problems/ALK13G). Briefly put:

Given a list of *N* numbers { *a*<sub>1</sub>, *a*<sub>2</sub>, …, *a*<sub>N</sub> }, find the range [*L*, *R*] (1 ≤ *L* ≤ *R* ≤ *N*) that maximizes the sum (*a*<sub>1</sub> + … + *a*<sub>L−1</sub>) − (*a*<sub>*L*</sub> + … + *a*<sub>R</sub>) + (*a*<sub>*R*+1</sub> + … + *a*<sub>N</sub>).

In other words, you get to multiply a subsection of the list by −1, and want to maximize the sum of the resulting list.

I looked at few of the solution like [this](http://www.codechef.com/viewsolution/2874792) but couldn't figure out what this guy is doing.

How would I go about this?

EXAMPLE

```
-2 3 -1 -4 -2
```

Now you can multiply the subsection 3 to 5 by -1 to get

```
-2 3 1 4 2
```

such that the `sum(-2,3,1,4,2) = 8` which is the maximum possible for this case

Comment: this question is going to be rubbish when the link is out of date

Comment: The link is working fine

Comment: @InsaneCoder what if the site administrator removes the page ?

Comment: Besides, you could provide a shorter description of the problem, I didn't care much for the plot and the character development is ridiculous

Comment: See the shorter description

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if we can find the minimum sequence from the array than that part if we multiply with one will give you max sum.

For example in this example : `-2 3 -1 -4 -2` the minimum sequence is -1, -4, -2. if we multiply this sequence with one it will maximise the sum. So the question is how to find minimum sum sequence.

Here come the O(N) solution:

- negate every number
- and run the [kadane's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem)

If the array contains all +ve than no subarray which needs to be multiplied by -1. Check the below question.  [minimum sum subarray in O(N) by Kadane's algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18472606/minimum-sum-subarray-in-on-by-kadanes-algorithm)

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm you have shown basically calculates the maximum sum and current sum up to any element.

**Note: It builds the array with opposite sign of the original elements**.

If the current sum is negative, then it rejects the original sum and starts a new sum with the new element.

If the current sum is positive, then that means including the previous entries is beneficial and it adds the current element to the sum.

Comment: can you suggest a better algorithm for the task

Comment: @InsaneCoder the algorithm is already O(N) time complexity. Any other algorithm shall be of at least this time complexity.

Comment: I mean a different strategy

Comment: @InsaneCoder The accepted solution is greedy actually, I don't think there exists a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, it sounds like you want to first find the minimum subarray and then multiply that by -1 and add the remaining non negated values.

The minimum subarray is essentially the opposite of [maximum subarray problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem):

```
public class MaxSumTest {
    public static class MaxSumList{
        int s=0, e=0;
        List<Integer> maxList;

        public MaxSumList(List<Integer> l){
            //Calculate s and e indexes
            minSubarray(l);

            //Negate the minSubarray
            for(int i=s; i < e; i++)
                l.set(i, -l.get(i));

            //Store list
            maxList = l;
        }

        public int minSubarray(List<Integer> l){
            int tmpStart = s;
            int currMin = l.get(0);
            int globalMin = l.get(0);

            for(int i=1; i<l.size(); i++){
                if(currMin + l.get(i) > 0){
                    currMin = l.get(i);
                    tmpStart = i;
                }
                else{
                    currMin += l.get(i);
                }
                if(currMin < globalMin){
                    globalMin = currMin;
                    s = tmpStart;
                    e = i+1;
                }
            }
            return globalMin;
        }
    }
    public static void main(String... args){
        MaxSumList ms = new MaxSumList(Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{-2, 3, -1, -4, -2}));
        //Prints [-2, 3, 1, 4, 2]
        System.out.println(ms.maxList);
    }
}
```